# 'XMLHttpRequest.prototype' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, object, null, xmlhttprequest, prototype

I have an issue that happened to an user of my web-application but that I can't reproduce locally.

The message is the one given in title:

```
 "'XMLHttpRequest.prototype' is null or not an object"
```

It occurs when trying to do "if (!XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary)"
The user told me he was using Mozilla firefox 4.0 but I can't even reproduce it using this version. I don't manage IE version under 8.

So, my question is:

- Can the problem only occur in some browsers?
- Does it have something to do regarding the cross-domain policy even though the message is not "access denied". Thus it would be some parameter to change on the server I guess.
- Is there a workaround ?

Of course, if you have another idea,feel free to mention it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes, `XMLHttpRequest` is a host object and before WebIDL standardised that/how Interfaces would need to be exposed using the `.prototype`, every environment might have done it its own way.

Comment: You can check if prototype is available so the error won't occur: `if (!XMLHttpRequest.prototype ||  !XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary)`

Comment: Not to dismiss the problems of the user, but Firefox 4.0 is horribly old. How important is the web application. Should it still support those old browsers? This to save you time searching for a solution on one specific users client.